# How to copy a file to my computer from another remote computer

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, shared-folders

One of my acquaintances wants to send me a file that is 10 GB in size but we're not on the same network, we're not even in the same city.

I told him I'll send him a URL of my computer where he can copy the file into. But it turns out my self-confidence was bigger than my networking skills as I'm still not able to solve this problem.

This is how I imagine this:

- He writes \\myip\$C\ReceivingFolder or something like this in his Windows explorer and my shared folder would open.
- It would use the public Internet, no same network
- Anyone from around the world would be able to copy files in that folder if he owns this path
- I don't care if it's risky

If this is impossible, I'm interested in any other solution that requires no third-party application/store only Windows built-in features and router settings (e.g. port-forwarding). At best we can use total commander if necessary.

Is transferring files between two computers via the public Internet possible in this way? How could I solve this? Please help!

Comment: You will have to use Remote Desktop (RDP) built into windows to transfer the file directly.

Comment: I don't want to share my whole computer with him, only 1 folder where he can copy to.

Comment: Then you will have to use dropbox or similar service.

Comment: Why? Is it impossible what I'm asking?

Comment: Yes it is impossible unless the other pc is on the same local network, you have not provided near enough information to get a good or accurate answer.

Comment: It is not impossible. It will require you to set up port forwarding on your router, identify your external address, and gather up a few other details. Doing so also exposes your network to certain risks. In your case, you might be better off handing him a flash drive.

Comment: If you're on the same network, then you haven't setup the share and authenticate to it correctly. Are you on a domain and both machines domain joined or are these both workgroup PCs on no domain? What username and password information are you trying when it does not work, like a credential from the machine with the share defined or what? How did you configure the share and NTFS permissions on the shared folder? Are you doing this with two computers over different Internet connections or on the same network. Please provide more detail.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, it was late in the night... The question is now updated, I hope this is enough information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti Then it may be technically possible by creating an SMB server share folder on your PC and setting the `1.` share level permissions to `everyone` perhaps or something equivalent, etc. for your Windows OS, `2.` NTFS permssions to allow `everyone` the `modify` level of access at this level. This means that anyone that connects to it is allowed to read or delete or modify existing or add new content as well. Opening it for everyone and anyone to do anything.

Comment: You would then setup the Internet facing router to allow incoming traffic from its Internet connection to forward the SMB/CIFS protocol ports (maybe TCP and UDP both so do some research) to the private IP address of the machine with the shared folder you setup. It may be ports 445 and 139 but do research, test, and confirm but this may be possible technically but I wouldn't do it but have fun with it regardless. There's a starting point for you to dig into some more if nothing more I suppose.

Comment: Otherwise, you might google search on setting up FTP on your Windows OS natively with no 3rd party software and configuring an anonymous access to it and then send him that path and you port forward your Internet router the FTP port 20 and 21 to the private IP of the FTP machine.